# How to import JSON Document into a Cloudant NoSQL DB

Tags: json, nosql, cloudant

I am attempting to import a json file into a Cloudant database.  As someone who has very little knowledge on the topic this simple task has seemed to be very difficult.  The video [Importing JSON documents into a NoSQL DB in Bluemix using NoSQLimport](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2017/01/importing-json-documents/) seems to have do what I am trying to accomplish, however, I am not able to follow along with what is being done.  Can someone explain the process a little bit more clearly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use the `_bulk_docs` endpoint. For example, create a file `test.json`:

```
cat test.json  
{
    "docs": [
        {
            "name": "stefan",
            "city": "bristol"
        },
        {
            "name": "bob",
            "city": "london"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can now upload that file using `curl` with each item in the `docs` array as a Cloudant document:

```
curl -XPOST 'https://U:P@ACCT.cloudant.com/DB/_bulk_docs' \
     -Hcontent-type:application/json -d @test.json

[
    {
        "ok":true,
        "id":"2fd7e2584e58da82703350669f3b065c",
        "rev":"1-acf5731c338adbd23311f7513ae2c2c2"
    },
    {
        "ok":true,
        "id":"2fd7e2584e58da82703350669f3b07aa",
        "rev":"1-3a1c83440d0c91fcdd095e286fea9fb5"
    }
]
```

If you open the Cloudant dashboard you should now be able to see the documents you uploaded.

[image: Cloudant dashboard]